# Rails and bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am studying the source code at the following Github repository:

https://github.com/asanderson15/rails-angular-tutorial/tree/master/part-2

After cloning and running the Rails server, view source shows all these following lines for the index page:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/main.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/underscore.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/main.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/Controllers/main/mainIndexCtrl.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/Controllers/main/mainPostCtrl.js?body=1"></script>
```

I am just puzzled to as where all those bootstrap-xxxxxx.js come from. They do not exist anywhere in any subfolders of assets or any other folders for that matter.  How does Rails know or what tells Rails to have them included in the generated HTML?

Comment: do you have bootstrap gem in your gemfile?

Comment: it's coming from gem. when you added require 'bootstrap' in your application.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Igor Kasyanchuk mentioned in a comment it's coming from bootstrap-sass gem from your [gemfile](https://github.com/asanderson15/rails-angular-tutorial/blob/master/part-2/Gemfile).